# Spring boot Jersey Jackson

Tags: json, spring, jersey, spring-boot

I have a question related to the Jackson configuration on my Spring boot project

As described on [spring boot blog](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring)

I try to customize my Object serialization.

After added a new config bean in my config

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();

    builder.propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    return builder;
}
```

When I try to output an instance of my class User the json result is not in CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES

```
Class User {
    private String firstName = "Joe Blow";

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
}
```

json output is :

```
{
  "firstName": "Joe Blow"
}
```

and not

```
{
  "first_name": "Joe Blow"
}
```

Maybe I need to register something in my Jersey config to activate my custom obejctMapper Config

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("my.package);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I directly configured the ObjectMapper as a Bean - not the Builder. Did you try that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The general way to configure the `ObjectMapper` for JAX-RS/Jersey applications is use a [`ContextResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html). For example

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
            PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES
        );
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

It should be picked up with the package scan, or you can explicitly register it, if it's not within the package scope

```
public JerseyConfig() {
    register(new ObjectMapperContextResolver());
    // Or if there's is an injection required
    // register it as a .class instead of instance
}
```

The `ContextResolver` is called during the marshalling and unmarshalling. The class/type being serialzed or deserialized into will be passed to the `getContext` method. So you could even use more than one mapper for different types, or even more use cases.

---

### UPDATE

Starting from Spring Boot 1.4, you can just create an `ObjectMapper` Spring bean, and Spring Boot will create the `ContextResolver` for you, and use your `ObjectMapper`

```
// in your `@Configuration` file.
@Bean
public ObjectMapper mapper() {}
```

Comment: It works but I'am pretty confused. As I can understand with this solution I configure the HK2 CDI and I no configure the Spring CDI.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Nothing about this solution involves HK2

Comment: Ok so register(new ObjectMapperContextResolver()); register my Provider in Spring CDI and Not Jersey CDI

Comment: I still don't understand what your question is. ContextResolver is a JAX-RS class. It has nothing to do with Spring. If you want to inject Spring beans into it, then you can make it a Spring component if you need to. For example if you have an `ObjectMapper` as a Spring bean, you could inject it into the ContextResolver.  But as of now, it is only used directly with Jersey and its request processing. Spring never gets involved.

Comment: I am using jackson fasterxml annotations on my POJOs for RESt web service and using @JasonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) does not make any difference, is above mentioned answer the only solution?