# Spring Boot 1.2.5 & Jersey 2 ignore null fields

Tags: json, jackson, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

In Spring boot 1.2.5 with a Jersey 2 interface, how can I set the JSON marshaller to not include fields that have null values?

For example:

```
[
    {
        "created": 1433987509174,
        "lastModified": 1433876475580,
        "id": 1,
        "example": "example1b"
    },
    {
        "created": 1434502031212,
        "lastModified": 1434502031212,
        "id": 10000,
        "example": "example1c"
    },
    {
        "created": 1439151444176,
        "lastModified": 1439151444176,
        "id": 10011,
        "example": null
    }
]
```

The field `"example": null` should not be included in the json output at all, but here it is specifying it is null.

In my @SpringBootApplication class, I've tried adding:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return converter;
}
```

or

```
@Bean
@Primary
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    return builder;
}
```

or

```
@Primary
@Bean
public ObjectMapper mapper() {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

and/or adding @JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL) to the Object itself

But it still produces the same response above with the `"example": null` included.

It was working on Spring 3.0.7 with `@JsonSerialize(include=Inclusion.NON_NULL)` but that no longer works now that I've ported to Spring Boot 1.2.5.

I believe I've followed the documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper and it's not working so I'm hoping someone might see something I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Also just tried adding the class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper mapper() {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

```
package com.my.spring;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.my.spring.service.rs.MyRestServiceImpl;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Configuration
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

    public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
        private final ObjectMapper mapper;

        public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
            mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        }

        @Override
        public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
           return mapper;
        }
    }

    public JerseyConfiguration() {
        register(new ObjectMapperContextResolver());
        register(MyRestServiceImpl.class); // My jax-rs implementation class
        property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true); // Not needed for this non_null issue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about mixing the Spring way (of configuring the mapper) and how Jersey handles this. But the Jersey way to configure the `ObjectMapper` is through a `ContextResolver`, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31703546/2587435).

Then register the `ObjectMapperContextResolver` with [your Jersey configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey/src/main/java/sample/jersey/JerseyConfig.java).

```
 public JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
     public JerseyConfig() {
         ...
         register(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);
     }
 }
```

Or if you are package scanning, the `@Provider` annotation will pick up the class.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense that there's a jersey mapper being used instead of the spring mapper since I opted for the JAX-RS interface. This solution works. Somehow that SO question didn't pop up in my search or it could've saved me quite a bit of confusion.