# Jersey Rest Client Post FormData Array

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am trying to post data via Jersey Client API. I have a class that is named "Channel". It has many fields but two field is needed while posting it. The below curl command is working fine.

```
curl -X POST \
     --header "XXX" \
     -d "[{\"name\":\"first\",\"protocol_name\":\"test\"}]" \
     "https://YYY.com"
```

I am using `Form` class in order to not send all of the field of `Channel` class. But i could not give array format in the request. When I use the below code, I am getting *"No serializer found for class javax.ws.rs.core.Form"* error. When I use non array of `Form` object, I am getting Bad Request error from server.

When I write a `Channel` class that has only two fields, I can send array of this `Channel` object and server is accepting it. But in this case I need to create a new class for that request. Also for the other requests, I will need create new classes.

```
Form [] forms = new Form[1];
forms[0] = new Form();
forms[0].param("name", newChannel.name);
forms[0].param("protocol_id", Integer.toString(newChannel.protocol_id));

String response = accept.post(Entity.entity(forms, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE), String.class);
```

Comment: _"When i write a Channel class that has only two fields, i can send array of this Channel object and server is accepting it. But in this case i need to create a new class for that request. Also for the other requests, i will need create new classes."_  - **Just do it**. This is the purpose of OOP. If you don't want do it, the other solutions look messy and ugly. Creating model classes is the cleanest and recommended way. `Form` will not work, as this is for `x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

Comment: You can also use a `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

Comment: When i need a request that uses three fields of Channel class, will i write another Channel class? How i will give names to that classes. How can i handle that?

Comment: List<Map<String, Object>>, this is worked thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI, there is a way, if you are using Jackson as the JSON provider, to ignore null values. Check out the solution at the bottom of [this _question_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31953492/2587435). You would register that `ObjectMapperContextResolver` with your `Client` or `WebTarget`