# Can't get HAL rendering with Spring HATEOAS and Jersey

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, spring-hateoas

I used the Spring Initializr (https://start.spring.io/ ) to create an app with only starters "Jersey (JAX-RS)" and "HATEOAS".
Then I added @EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HAL), but I just can't get links rendered correctly in HAL format.

The format I aim for:

```
{
    "name": "Hello",
    "count": 42,
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/foo"
        }
    }
}
```

What I currently get instead:

```
{
    "name": "Hello",
    "count": 42,
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/foo"
        }
    ]
}
```

Besides the classes generated by the initializr, I added this configuration

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("api")
@Component
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HAL)
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        registerEndpoints();
    }

    private void registerEndpoints() {
        register(FooResource.class);
    }
}
```

this resource (endpoint):

```
@Component
@Path("foo")
public class FooResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
    public Resource<Foo> getFoo() {

        final Resource<Foo> fooTo = new Resource<>(new Foo("Hello", 42));

        fooTo.add(JaxRsLinkBuilder.linkTo(FooResource.class).withRel("self"));

        return fooTo;
    }
}
```

and a dummy bean:

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;
    private int count;

    public Foo() {
    }

    public Foo(String name, int count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

I also tried adding

```
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HAL)
```

next to the @SpringBootApplication on the application class.

When I

```
GET localhost:8080/api/foo
```

I get a response with correct content type

```
application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
```

but still the wrong format ("link" property as array instaed of "_links" property as object/map).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add to the answer from @zerflagL, to register the `Jackson2HalModule`, you should use a `ContextResolver`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31703546/2587435). Also on top of this module, you need to configure the [`HalHandlerInstantiator`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-hateoas/0.19.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/hateoas/hal/Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator.html) with the `ObjectMapper`. If you miss the last part, you will get exceptions about Jackson not being able to instantiate the serializers because of no default constructor.

```
@Provider
public class JacksonContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public JacksonContextResolver() {
        mapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
        mapper.setHandlerInstantiator(new HalHandlerInstantiator(
                new AnnotationRelProvider(), null, null));
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Then just register the context resolver with your Jersey `ResourceConfig`

```
register(new JacksonContextResolver());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is working! I was under the impression that JAX-RS was a valid/supported option in Spring HATEOAS because there even is a JaxRsLinkBuilder class. It turned out that the JaxRsLinkBuilder is much less useful (to put it mildly) than the ControllerLinkBuilder, because it does not even support methodOn() for building links, nor does it support JAX-RS sub-resources.

So I am now using my own HAL implementation instead of Spring HATEOAS and got also rid of Spring Web in the process.

Comment: I've been meaning to explore [this library](https://github.com/HalBuilder) but haven't gotten around to it yet. Maybe something you can check out.

Answer (score 3):

Spring HATEOAS was developed to work with Spring MVC. Everything related to JSON serialization / deseralization is registered for Spring MVC, `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to be precise.

If you want the same for Jersey you would have to set up Jackson so that `org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule` gets registered.