# Producing JSON fails silently using Jersey with Hibernate

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jersey, jackson

As soon as a relationship is saved to db then the issue appears. Firstly, I'm not able to see the exception. My feeling is that it is happening due to the relationship references I have added to my classes because as soon as I make the references private then I receive the JSON objects on the client side whereas previously it would return status 500.

Initially used Jersey with JAXB to generate JSON response and now trying to use Jackson.

There are two main classes with a one to many relationship, Category and SubCategory.

I have two issues:

> 1 ) Why does jersey fail to generate JSON response ??
>
> 2 ) How to print the exception to console ??

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    public Long id;
    
    @Column(name="Name", length=50)
    public String name;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="category")
    public Set<SubCategory> subCategories;
    
    @Column(name="Created_On")
    public Date createdOn;
    
    public Category() {
        // nothing
    }
    
    public static List<Category> getCategories() {
        Session session = HibernateService.getSession().openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Category.class);
        return criteria.list();
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class SubCategory {
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    public Long id;
    
    @Column(name="Name", length=50)
    public String name;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Category_ID")
    public Category category;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="subCategory")
    public Set<Product> products;
    
    @Column(name="Created_On")
    public Date createdOn;
    
    public SubCategory() {
        // nothing
    }
    
    public static List<SubCategory> getSubCategories() {
        Session session = HibernateService.getSession().openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SubCategory.class);
        return criteria.list();
    }
}
```

---

Service methods:

```
@Path("/")
public class Service {
@GET
    @Path("/categories")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        List<Category> categories = Category.getCategories();
        return categories;
    }
    
    @GET
    @Path("/subcategories")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<SubCategory> getSubCategories() {
        List<SubCategory> subCategories = SubCategory.getSubCategories();
        return subCategories;
    }
}
```

---

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.24</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
         -->

        
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Try to [configure jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31703546/2587435) with the [Hibernate5Module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate)

Comment: Correct but before that I had to remove jersey-media-moxy from pom.xml.