# Automatic add Root Element in JAXB

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jaxb, jersey

In Jersey, how can I **automatically** add root in JAXB pojo?

I have my JAXB pojo

```
class Product {
   private String name;
   ....
}
```

By default the generated json is

```
{
    "name": "Burton Custom Freestlye 151",
}
```

I would like it to be

```
{
  "product": {
    "name": "Burton Custom Freestlye 151",
  }
}
```

Note: What I mean by **automatic** is not creating separate class just to enclose another pojo.

This should be in serialization/deserialization into JSON.

Also I have other JSON don't use root element.

Comment: Why JAXB? JAXB is for XML not for JSON, which JAXB implementation do you use? MOXy ?

Comment: The default one from spring boot starter jersey

Comment: jersey is a `JAX-RS` implementation. Your question is really confusing. What you want is to know how to make your rest resource returns a result in JSON using the format that you provide in last, right? If so please improve your question because for now it is really misleading.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot, you can just configure an `ObjectMapper` as a Spring bean, and Spring Boot is set up where Jersey will use the mapper. The configuration property for the `ObjectMapper` to automatically add a root element is

> [`SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRAP_ROOT_VALUE)

The default behavior is to take the class name and lower case it. If you want something different you can annotation the class with `@XmlRootElement("newName")` or `@JsonRootName("newName")`. To make a Spring bean just add the following in your configuration class

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper mapper() {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_NAME, true);
    return mapper;
}
```

Note I think this (creating a Spring bean for the ObjectMapper) is only available starting from 1.4.0. If you are using a earlier version of Boot, you should just [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31703546/2587435).

Also if you are expecting incoming JSON with the wrapped value, you will also want to *unwrap* it. You can do that with

> [`DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE)

Configure it the same way as above (passing `true`).

---

### UPDATE

(Not very useful at this point, but maybe in the future)

Looking at the [source for `@JsonRootName`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRootName.java#L45), it seems Jackson has been planning on adding an `alwaysWrap` property in the annotation since 2.4. But I guess they have been delaying this. Not sure why. Maybe in the future it'll show up.

Comment: I have other JSON don't use root element, how can I do this for specific pojos only?

Comment: Use the option I linked to (for boot < 1.4.0). You can configure different mappers. In the `getContext` method, you can determine which type should get the root wrapper. It' s a bit of work having to keep track of all the classes that need it, but I think that may be your best option.