# Where to register custom ObjectMapper for my REST Service application?

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, jersey, jackson

I am building a REST service application with Spring and Jersey.

The "Response Content Type" can be either JSON or XML, which is why I use JAXB annotations on the fields of my POJO, which works great so far. No configuration was needed to get this to work, I just put the required .jars on the classpath.

Now, I want to add custom behaviour for (de-)serialization of Java 8 Date/Time objects and register the `JavaTimeModule` from Jackson.

Where would be the right place to register the Module? I know the code snippet is supposed to look something like this:

```
ObjectMapper tmpMapper = new ObjectMapper();
tmpMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

But where do I actually put this code?

The place that comes to mind is my `ResourceConfig` class from Jersey. It looks like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ApplicationResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationResourceConfig() {
    // Not needed because since jersey 2.9 JacksonFeature implements AutoDiscoverable
    // register(JacksonFeature.class);

    register(WadlFeature.class);

    // Registers our own request listener for monitoring purposes
    register(RestServiceApplicationEventListener.class);

    // Registers the package that contains our REST resources
    packages(PingResource.class.getPackage().getName());
}
```

What I did now was to add the following lines at the bottom of the constructor:

```
ObjectMapper tmpMapper = new ObjectMapper();
tmpMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
JacksonJaxbJsonProvider tmpProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
tmpProvider.setMapper(tmpMapper);
register(tmpProvider);
```

The DateTime conversion now worked. However, some of the the JAXB behaviour changed which caused the deserialization of other beans to break. Here is what is not working anymore:

I have super class which defines a getter of a field:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
   @XmlElement(name = "yourField")
   public abstract String getMyField();
}
```

(This maps the internal name of the field to different name which is exposed to the outside)

```
public class SubClass {
    private String myField;

    @Override
    public String getMyField() {
        return myField;
    }
}
```

This mechanism used to work before and I could e.g. define a POST parameter of type SubClass calling the method with a JSON snippet that looks like this:

```
{
    "yourField" : "hello world"
}
```

When trying this now I get the exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "yourField" (class com.myProject.SubClass), not marked as ignorable (1 known property: "myField"])
at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@728b1889; line: 4, column: 14] (through reference chain: com.myProject.Subclass["yourField"])
```

Note however, that the basic JAXB features still work, only in this particular superclass/subclass example.

Could it be that explicitly registering a `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` somehow altered the default behaviour on how to deal with JAXB annotated beans? Is there a way to maybe retrieve the existing `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` (that must have been registered implicitly somehow) or the existing `ObjectMapper` object and register the `JavaTimeModule` to it instead of creating a new Mapper object and a new Provider object?

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31703546/2587435)

Comment: It still gives me the same error message. I just realized this even happens if I annotate the field in the subclass, too with @XmlElement(name = "yourField")

Comment: And you're saying that it was working before trying to use your custom ObjectMapper?

Comment: Yes. It is as if it the annotation is ignored now.

Comment: Try registering the JaxbAnnotationModule with the ObjectMapper

Comment: Wow, this seems to work, thanks!!!

Out of interest: is it possible to somehow access the existing mapper that has been used before and simply register an additional module (like my JavaTimeModule) instead of creating a new mapper and register once again all the modules that I need?

Comment: Well internally, an ObjectMapper is not used. Jackson will use ObjectWriter and ObjectReader. And no, I'm not sure how to tap into this, that's why I suggested what I did :/